# Cannot write datanode pid /tmp/hadoop-hdfs-datanode.pid

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

After running `stop-dfs.sh` followed by `start-dfs.sh` from the Namenode, one of the Datanodes raised the error:

```
Cannot write datanode pid /tmp/hadoop-hdfs-datanode.pid
```

I checked the permissions for the `hadoop-hdfs-datanode.pid` and the `hadoop` user had permission.

Note: I've already solved the problem, I'm posting this for future as I was unable to find a solution online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the machine running the Datanode was out of space and this wasn't reflected in the raised error. `df -h` is handy for Debian systems. After cleaning some space and running `start-dfs.sh` from the Namenode all Datanodes were running successfully.